# How to prevent useEffect in customHook being called with every import of custom hook?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks

I'm writing chat app using react js and socket.io library.

All the logic where I subscribe to events form server and emit some events is written in useEffect of custom hook.

Then I return all data I need from this custom hook and reuse it in components that I need. However, I realized that logic written in useEffect is called every time I import this custom hook to external component.

If I put all the logic outside of useEffect, it's called even more times than custom hook is imported.

How do I prevent it if it's possible at all?

If it's not possible, what solution could you please suggest? I don't want to use redux for this app, I thought to keep everything in this custom hook component and just reuse data from it where I need.

I can't share working example because it won't work without server part so here is a simple codesandbox example. You can see in console that it's rendered twice.

https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-hook-bfc5j?file=/src/useChat.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It renders twice because you call `useChat()` two times in your app (one in **App.js**, other in **Text.js**) What you can do is to create a reference of useChat component in your App.js and pass is as a prop to Text.js like:

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import useChat from "./useChat";
import Text from "./Text";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const myUseChat = useChat();
  const { printMessage } = myUseChat;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={printMessage}>Print</button>
      <Text myUseChat={myUseChat} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Text.js

```
import React from "react";
import useChat from "./useChat";
import "./styles.css";

export default function Text(props) {
  const { text } = props.myUseChat;

  return <div className="App">{text}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But what if my chat structure doesn't allow me to pass props to all components where I need data? Is there a way to still get this data from custom hook without extra re-renders that are caused by imports?

Comment: Then I think only `redux` or `context-api` can work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set up some side effects once but also consume the resulting data in multiple places, one way is to use the [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext) feature.

```js
// ws/context.jsx, or similar

const WsContext = React.createContext(defaultValue);

export const WsProvider = props => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(someInitialValue);
  useEffect(() => {
    // do expensive things, call setValue with new results
  });
  return (
    <WsContext.Provider value={value}>
      {props.children}
    </WsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useCustomHook = () => {
  const value = useContext(WsContext);

  // perhaps do some other things specific to this hook usage

  return value;
};
```

You can expect the hook to work in any component that is a descendant of `<WsProvider>` in React's rendered tree of elements.

If you use the hook in a non-descendant of the provider component, the value returned will be the `defaultValue` we initialized the context instance with.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'd like to specify one thing though. You are saying: "You can expect the hook to work in any component that is a descendant of.." but what if not only want the hook to work, but I want to use specific data returned by that hook, how can I do it? Do I still need to import that data from hook? Won't it still be causing re-renders? Sorry, I never used context providers, it's a bit confusing to me.

Comment: The data will not be created over and over again, it will be created and stored as state of the provider component. Calling the hook in a downstream component will let you access that data. When the data changes (e.g. you receive a socket message), yes, the Provider and its children will re-render. But the `useEffect` does not have to run every time you re-render.